# Is there a lighter mutex than std::mutex for single-writer single-reader data protection?

Tags: c++, mutex

I have a struct and I know there is only 1 thread that writes it and only 1 thread that reads it.

```
struct Data {
    // Various data members
    int a;
    double b;
    std::string c;
    std::vector<LargeGadget> d;  // LargeGadget is a custom defined type. 
    // For data protection: is there a lighter alternative to std::mutex ?
    std::mutex lock;
};

// I am looking for a lighter lock implementation because this vector can hold a lot of Data*.
std::vector<Data*> data;

// The writer/reader thread grabs the lock before writing/reading the data fields.
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(data.front()->lock);
```

I am hoping the assumption that only 1 thread that writes data and only 1 thread that reads data will need a lighter lock than `std::mutex`.

I don't want to use any lock-less single-writer single-reader queue structure for this because `struct Data` could grow large.

Comment: Since your `Data` contains a vector of `LargeGadget` objects, does the binary representation size of `std::mutex` really matter?

Comment: What do you mean by *lighter*?

Comment: You may be interested in futexes; see, e.g., https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2018/basics-of-futexes/. There is even an exemplary implementation of a mutex class by using a futex internally, which requires only a single atomic member variable. However, the code is not portable, since it needs to call futex-related syscalls.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Does spinlock solve it?